# carousel bootstrap images not overlapping each other

Tags: html, carousel

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="Carousel slide" data-ride="Carousel" data-interval="1000">
        <ol class="Carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="Carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active" alt="Slide 1">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/water.jpg" alt="Slide 2">
                <div class="Carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Theme1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/ice.jpg">
                <div class="Carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Theme2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left Carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>

        <a class="right Carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBuXP.png)
my pictures are not overlapping each other why but my code is correct i am using bootstrap examples but what is the reason i dont know this images not coming in one way over each other

Comment: please set up a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Hi its becz of your class check your class name

```
class="carousel-inner"
```

but you mentioned

```
class="Carousel-inner"
```

i changed here now it ok

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
     <div class="carousel-inner">


     <div class="item active" alt="Slide 1">
     <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Slide 2">
     <div class="Carousel-caption">
     <h1>Theme1</h1>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item ">
     <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img_chania2.jpg">
             <div class="Carousel-caption">
     <h1>Theme2</h1>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
     </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```